# Regex split newlines - keep captured line break characters at end of match

Tags: c#, regex

I need to split a text into its lines. But I also need to keep the line break characters at each line.

```
var text = "abc\r\ndef";  // should be two lines and 8 characters
// var text = "abc\rdef"; // should be two lines and 7 characters
// var text = "abc\ndef"; // should be two lines and 7 characters
var lines = Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=[\r\n|\r|\n])");
// I was hoping it would split into two lines:
// "abc\r\n"
// "def"
var countChars = 0;
foreach (var line in lines)
{
     countChars += line.Length;
}

Assert.That(countChars, Is.EqualTo(8));
Assert.That(lines.Length, Is.EqualTo(2));
```

It did not feel so complicated in the beginning but I cannot make it work. Perhaps someone has a hint?

Comment: I think you need an `@` at your pattern string

Comment: Thanks, I added it, but it does not change the behavior.

Comment: I was just point out that to you :)

Comment: `[\r\n|\r|\n]` matches one of the characters `\r`, `\n` or `|`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the lookbehind pattern is tried at every position inside the string, and it can find the position the is immediately preceded with `\r`, with `\n` and with `\r\n` in your string. More, `[\r\n|\r|\n]` is just the same as `[\r|\n]`, it matches a CR, LF or a pipe chars.

If you want to make sure you only match a position immediately preceded with CRLF, or a CR that has no LF after it, or an LF that has no CR before it, you can use

```cs
(?<=\r\n|(?<!\r)\n|\r(?!\n))
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5Cr%5Cn%7C%28%3F%3C!%5Cr%29%5Cn%7C%5Cr%28%3F!%5Cn%29%29&i=abc%0D%0Adef&l=8), it matches:

- `(?<=` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with

  - `\r\n` - a  CRLF sequence
  - `|` - or
  - `(?<!\r)\n` - an LF not immediately preceded with a CR
  - `|` - or
  - `\r(?!\n)` - a CR not immediately followed with an LF
- `)` - end of the lookbehind.

See the [C# demo](https://ideone.com/8fQNIe):

```cs
var text = "abc\r\ndef";
    foreach (var s in Regex.Split(text, @"(?<=\r\n|(?<!\r)\n|\r(?!\n))"))
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}'",s);
```

Output:

```cs
'abc
'
'def'
```